# How to make sure code in a .click() event has finished before it runs again

Tags: jquery

I have a .click() that runs various functions with animations. These animations depend on the current position of the elements and so if the button is clicked a second time before the previous animation runs, it will be slightly off.

Let's say my code is written like:

```
$('.button').click(function() {

    if (condition A)
       ExecuteAnimation1;
    else if (condition B)
       ExecuteAnimation2;

});
```

How can I ensure the animation function has completed before calling them? Would I use the .queue() method?

Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at promises? Using them on your animations would work. If you paste an example of your animation code, then I could give you a full example.

Comment: You could unbind the click event as soon as it's called, and then re-bind it after the animation completes.

Comment: Depending on your exact requirements for the animation, you may achieve what you're after just by calling `.stop(true, true)` or similar before the animation: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var IS_BUSY_ANIMATING = false;

function start_animation() {
  if (IS_BUSY_ANIMATING) {
    setTimeout(startAnimation, 2000); //TRY after 2 seconds
  }

  IS_BUSY_ANIMATING = true;

  if (condition A)
    ExecuteAnimation1;
  else if (condition B)
    ExecuteAnimation2;

  IS_BUSY_ANIMATING = false;
} 

$('.button').click(start_animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify @blunderboy like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var animation_disabled = false;
   $('.button').click(function() {
    if(!animation_disabled){
       animation_disabled = true;
       if (condition A)
          ExecuteAnimation1;
       else if (condition B)
          ExecuteAnimation2;
       animation_disabled = false;
     }
   });
});
```